# power spectrum of passband of ofdm is it right shape or not?

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, ofdm, bandpass, bpsk

I tried to get power spectrum of ofdm passband signal.
Below is the whole matlab code for that with BPSK+ofdm.
and I got the power spectrum as below.
I wonder that is that right form or not?

[image: full span]
[image: main band]

```
Nfft=64; % number of sub carriers
Ncp=Nfft/4; % number of cyclic prefix
Nuc=52; % number of used carriers

d=2*(randn(1,Nuc)>0.5)-1; % bpsk mapped data

X=zeros(1,Nfft);
X([2:Nuc/2+1,(end-Nuc/2)+1:end])=d; % only used sub carrier
x=ifft(X,Nfft); % time domain
sbb=[x(end-Ncp+1:end) x]; % to add cyclic prefix

%% passband 

fc=4; % carrier frequency
sps=16; % samples per symbol
Tsym=1; % symbol duration time
Ts=Tsym/sps; % sampling time
fs=1/Ts;

Tmax=(Nfft+Ncp)*sps*Ts-Ts;
t=0:Ts:Tmax;

%return

% I-ch up-sampling
I=real(sbb);
I=repmat(I,sps,1);
I=I(:).';
sI=I.*cos(2*pi*fc*t);

% Q-ch up-sampling
Q=imag(sbb);
Q=repmat(Q,sps,1);
Q=Q(:).';
sQ=Q.*-sin(2*pi*fc*t);

s=sI+sQ; % transimt signal

%% plot power spectrum

f=(0:(numel(s)-1))/numel(s)*fs;

figure
plot(f,10*log10(abs(fft(s))))
%plot(f/1e6,10*log10(abs(fft(s))))
xlabel('frequency[Hz]');
ylim([-40 20]);
title('full span');
grid on

figure
plot(f,10*log10(abs(fft(s))))
%plot(f/1e6,10*log10(abs(fft(s))))
xlabel('frequency[Hz]');
ylim([-40 20]);
xlim([3 5])
title('main band');
grid on
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look right. a 64-FFT with only the center 52 carriers occupied should look pretty "rectangular".

I'd recommend not doing the upconversion. OFDM is designed to be an equivalent-baseband system, so you can definitely investigate whether your OFDM works directly in baseband. It's way more intuitive that way.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Using the matlab code above, the spectral shape for the baseband sbb variable shows a right angle shape as you say. As you said, if there is a problem with the waveform of the passband, please explain which part of the matlab code above.

[![baseband][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3H1P.png

Comment: well, I think that's up to you to debug. Generally, I would recommend *not* mixing things up – it simply has no benefit, unless you're planning to simulate any nonlinear channels. Also, mixing up could be represented by two lines of code: multiplication with a complex sinusoid, and then deletion of the imaginary part. So, honestly, not debugging your code!